# Reducing boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

So I got this equation: `(NOT A + B) x ( A + C)`

When I try to reduce this I get `(Not A AND C) OR (A AND B) OR (B AND C)` But wolframalpha.com([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Not%28A%29%20or%20B%29%20and%20%28%20A%20or%20C%29)) says it ends up being `A'C + AB`. I also tried to input my original reduction and got this ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28Not%20A%20AND%20C%29%20OR%20%28A%20AND%20B%29%20OR%20%28B%20AND%20C%29)) whitch gave me the same result. How does `(B AND C)` just get reduced to nothing?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem):

\begin{align*}
A'C + AB + BC
&= A'C + AB + (1)BC \\
&= A'C + AB + (A + A')BC \\
&= A'C + AB + (ABC + A'BC) \\
&= (A'C + A'BC) + (AB + ABC) \\
&= A'C(1 + B) + AB(1 + C) \\
&= A'C(1) + AB(1) \\
&= A'C + AB \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Note by logical definitions: if either $B$ or $C$ hold, then either ($A'$ and $C$) or ($A$ and $B$) must hold.

If you want to go purely with formal addition/multiplication, we can note that
$$
A'C + AB + BC= \\
A'C + AB + (A + A')BC= \\
A'C + AB + ABC + A'BC =\\
A'(C + BC) + A(B + BC) =\\
A'C(1 + B) + AB(1 + C) =\\
A'C + AB
$$
If you're interested in *computing* such reductions, look into [Karnaugh maps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).